# What does the designators mean in this picture?

Tags: windows, active-directory

I'm reading some Windows AD security PDF, and I came to this one

[image]

It says `Use designators to clearly identify admin rights: -ada, -sa, -wa`, what does that mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably means that you should suffix the user names with "-ada" (for example) if the user is an ADAdministrator, example: jdoe should be jdoe-ada if this account is an AD Admin.

This allows you to see at a glance that it's a privileged account and that it must be used knowingly.

Comment: Additionally, this helps to discourage to use admin accounts for normal work. Administrators should have two accounts, one without special privileges and a second account for administrative tasks.